# CloudKit public database deleted record

Tags: swift, cloudkit

Suppose I have local cache with core data of a public CloudKit database.
With a private database a device gets a list of changes that occurred while it was offline.

If I delete a record via the dashboard from the public database, then how will devices be made aware of this change? Zones and delta-lists are not available for public databases as far as I can tell. What's the trick here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Detecting changes in the public database is also handled via subscriptions, but there are different types of subscriptions for different aspects of cloudkit. As noted at https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1917/_index.html (**emphasis** added)

> Note: The initializers for creating a CKSubscription object with a
>   subscriptionID are deprecated, so use CKQuerySubscription,
>   CKRecordZoneSubscription, or CKDatabaseSubscription on iOS 10.0+,
>   macOS 10.12+, and tvOS 10.0+. Be aware that **CKQuerySubscription is not
>   supported in the shared database**, and **CKDatabaseSubscription currently
>   only tracks the changes from custom zones in the private and shared
>   database.**

So, you'll need to use a `CKQuerySubscription` to detect changes in the public database. With a `CKQuerySubscription` you will specify a record type, optional search parameters (via `NSPredicate`) and specify if the subscription should fire on creation, update, and/or deletion of the record.

The app will then receive a push notification when the trigger condition is met and is responsible to update the user's local data store as appropriate.

Comment: Ok, what if the app is not working, and the app is launched 3 days later, when hundreds changes were performed on public database? How can I fetch CHANGES, not all the records?

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk .shouldSendContentAvailable = true gives your app some background execution time to handle any notification